# Drupal 7 vocabulary page

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming, drupal-templates

I've created a custom page for a specific vocabulary (using zen theme)

```
page--vocabulary--2.tpl.php
```

Works so far as I can customise the page, but I cannot for the life of me work out how to render a custom field (field_banner). Very new to drupal, I can find the field at

```
$page['content']['term']['#term']->field_banner
```

Basically, on a per 'term' basis, I want to display an array of images (field_banner) at the header of the template. Hope my question makes sense, still overwhelmed by the Drupal way of thinking, so rather confused!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to make sure the field gets loaded on that page. Is it a node ?

What I suggest is you install the dev module and when you see your page you should see dev tab. In that tab you need to find your field set to access. Once you find  it in the list then you can access it in your template file.

The code should look something like this

```
$node->field_link['und'][0]['value']
```

[image: where to find it]

Comment: ah! no the $node variable isn't set, thanks for the suggestion. how can I load the node into the page template?

Comment: ah but the field is loaded onto the page as $page['content']['term']['#term']->field_banner so what use is this?

Comment: paste the link here for me to check